# how to Scroll image on hover in a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I am trying to create an effect somewhat like that https://cuberto.com/contacts/ (Hover on the silver-bordered buttons Ex: site from scratch, UX/UI Design, or click on the menu on the top right side and hover on menu items) I am trying to create the same effect but with the images Like whenever I hover the Images the image have to go up and come from beneath (might be the second image) I tried to do that but didn't get the right way how to implement this thing. I searched all over the internet but didn't get the answer not even from Youtube and here at StackOverflow so I wanna know how to do this thing correctly and have any idea what this effect is called?

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

```css
.wrapper{
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:300px;
 
  
}
.wrapper img{
  position:absolute; 
  transition:.5s ease-in-out;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.wrapper .image-front:hover{
    transform:translateY(-400px);
  transition:.5s ease-in-out;
}
/* .image-back{
    transform:translateY(200px);
  
} */

.wrapper .image-back:hover .wrapper {
    transform:translateY(200px);
  transition:.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="wrapper">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1648737119359-510d4f551382?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwyMXx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="" class="image-back">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1648737119359-510d4f551382?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwyMXx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="" class="image-front">
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the problem? Is it that when the image no longer under the mouse it starts to come down and then bounce up again when it is under the mouse?

Comment: @ITgoldman I just want to create a effect which I mentioned and by the way Someone has already answered that below you can have a look thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `:hover` to the parent element.

I've also adjusted the wrapper height to match the height of the images and used this height within the `translateY`s.

```css
.wrapper{
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:333px;   
}

.wrapper img{
  position:absolute; 
  transition:.5s ease-in-out;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.wrapper:hover .image-front{
  transform:translateY(-333px);
  transition:.5s ease-in-out;
}

.image-back{
    transform:translateY(333px);      
}

.wrapper:hover .image-back {
  transform:translateY(0);
  transition:.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="wrapper">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1648737119359-510d4f551382?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwyMXx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="" class="image-back">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1648737119359-510d4f551382?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwyMXx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="" class="image-front">
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help I highly appreciate that! and if you feel the question might be helpful for the people you can upvote it.

Comment: improvement: the wrapper should be inline-block

Answer (score 0):

Go to the page you are referring to and right click and hit inspect what you are trying to look at replicating the style. For example I did it to the site from scratch up and got the below in the browser console. Take a look at the style or classes attributed to what you are looking for.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvHUR.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).